# a[type="application/pdf"] vs a[href$=".pdf"]

Tags: css

What is the difference between these 2 selectors     `a[type="application/pdf"]` and `a[href$=".pdf"]`

```
a[type="application/pdf"] { 
  background-image: url(/images/pdf.gif);
  padding-left: 20px;
}

a[href$=".pdf"] { 
  background-image: url(/images/pdf.gif);
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One does MIME type matching and the other does extension globbing. You should probably use the first one because not everyone uses file extensions.

Comment: are both compatible in all browser except IE6? I know IE 6 doesn't support these

Comment: Yes. All major browsers except IE support it.

Comment: For example: You mean even if we keep `.gif` extension for PDF even this will work `a[type="application/pdf"]`

Comment: Attribute selectors aren't understood by IE6 and are OK in IE7+, you're right. Example in action: the two PDF icons in notes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Burns_Effect#References

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: as long as the "type" attribute is "application/pdf".

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer isn't completely correct. No selector does "MIME type matching".

`a[type="application/pdf"]` will match all links where the "type" attribute is set to "application/pdf". If you want to display a PDF icon you'll need to add `type="application/pdf"` to all the approprite links.

This is exactly what the `type` attribute on links is intended for (see [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-type-A)), to provide a "hint" to the MIME type. However, the browser doesn't actually know what the type of a file is until it starts downloading it. Just wanted to clear that up.

The other selector, `a[href$=".pdf"]`, matches the URL of the link only. It will match any links that end in `.pdf`, whether they are actually PDF files or not. And of course, it won't match URLs like `file.pdf?v=2`.

Your best bet is to mark all links to PDF files manually, either with the `type` attribute, or since you want IE-compatibility, just a regular class instead.

Comment: can't we use `a[href$=".pdf*"]` like this?

Comment: You can use `a[href*=".pdf"]` to match any URL that contains `.pdf` in it. But as I was trying to imply, that is not very reliable. Whatever the case, for reliability you need to explicitly specify that a link is a PDF somehow, whether you add a simple class or use the `type` attribute described above.